# on_reaction_add not being run

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to discord.py and trying to make a translator bot. When the user reacts with a certain flag, the bot translates it, but the event is never getting called hence I have no code to translate any messages yet. I know it's not getting called because the program isn't printing an `'x'` to the console.

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    channel = reaction.message.channel
    print('x')
    await client.send_message(channel, '{} has added {} to the the message {}'.format(user.name, reaction.emoji, reaction.message.content))

    await client.process_commands(reaction.message)
```

Comment: According to the [Event Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add), "if the message is not found in the `Client.messages` cache, then this event will not be called."  Could that be part of your problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't much valid reason for why the event isn't registered/called.

One of which is stated in the docs: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add. Try adding a reaction immediately to a message that is sent after the bot is online. Since messages sent before the bot is online will not be recognized by the bot (not in `Client.messages`).

> if the message is not found in the `Client.messages` cache, then this
>   event will not be called.

Another possible reason is that this function was never defined before the client loop commenced. Verify your indentation. And/Or try placing the function directly under `client = Bot(...)`, to check if this is the problem.

If neither of the aforementioned solves your problem, please post a minimal, complete, verifiable example (a short runnable code from top to bottom that indicates your problem).

Comment: Works on new messages not already made ones :) @PatrickHaugh yes thats the reason, I was trying it on old messages, cheers :)

Comment: Do you know a way to force specific old messages into the cache? One can use `logs_from` in order to get messages, but that doesn't appear to put them in the cache...

Comment: Did you ever find a way @Shadow? I tried get_channel -> fetch_message, but it doesn't add it to the cache either?

Comment: @EhsanKia sorry - but this happened years ago... I think I worked around the issue by putting my bot in a specific channel so that the message history never got too large for it to really matter.

Comment: I ended up using on_raw_reaction_add which doesn't have this issue

Answer (score 14):

Probably a bit late to this thread but, the answer above is a valid answer. But you can also use `on_raw_reaction_add` which gets called even if the messages aren't in the Bot's cache.

> Called when a message has a reaction added. Unlike on_reaction_add(), this is called regardless of the state of the internal message cache.

[Documentation Link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.on_raw_reaction_add)

Example:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    channel = await self.bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    user = await self.bot.fetch_user(payload.user_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji

    await channel.send("Hello")
```