# find the function that save an image when react to on discord

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am new to building discord bots.

So I created a bot, manage to make him talk etc. (I use Python 3.6)

I am now trying to copy an image from a channel to send it somewhere else. 
I can't find the function that checks if I reacted to the image neither the one to save an image.

What i want to do is : If an someone reacts to an image with the :white_check_mark: , the bot copies it.

If someone already did it and can show it to me would be awesome.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways an image could be in a message.  It could be an attachment to that message, where you upload an image from your computer to Discord, or it could be in an embed, which is what happens when you paste a link in Discord.

Users react to messages, not images.  Whenever a user reacts to a message your bot is aware of, it triggers the `on_reaction_add` event.  We can put code in that event to check for a certain reaction and then save the files.

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.emoji == '\N{WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK}':
        for embed in reaction.message.embeds:
            if embed.url is not discord.Embed.Empty:
                url = embed.url
                name = url[url.rfind('/')+1:]
                async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                    async with session.get(url) as resp:
                        if resp.status == 200:
                            with open(f'imgs/{name}', 'wb+') as file:
                                file.write(await resp.read())
        for attachment in reaction.message.attachments:
            await attachment.save(f'imgs/{attachment.filename}')
```

I wrote this for the more recent rewrite branch, version 1.0.  If you're using the older async branch, 0.16, then you will need to change how attachment saving works. I believe that attachments in the older versions were stored as dictionaries, rather than as attachment objects.

Keep in mind that [`on_reaction_add` is only run for messages that your bot has cached.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785641/on-reaction-add-not-being-run/50785788#50785788)   Reactions on older messages won't trigger the event.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much. 
I will check this right now. If my bot runs 24/7, someone posts an image, someone else posts an image and a 3rd person reacts with the check emoji on the three image, will they be saved?

Comment: If the message was sent while your bot was up, and isn't too old, the event will trigger.  I believe the message cache stores around the last 2000 messages that the bot has seen, so they do "expire" after a while.

Comment: So i just tested, I get this error: "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save''.

Comment: That would mean you're using the async branch.  You can probably get `attachment['url']`, and then reuse the code for embeds.

Comment: I am a bit lost. I did this: discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/intro.html#installing. I downloaded the rewrite branch. Correct me if I am wrong (like i said very knew to the discord development so a bit lost). Here is the full code I get: 
Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\discord bots\Success\Success\SuccessCopy.py", line 24, in on_reaction_add
    await attachment.save(f'imgs/{attachment.filename}')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: That's odd.  For the rewrite branch, [`Message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Message.attachments) should be a list of `Attachment` objects.  Try putting a `print(discord.__version__)` at the top of your file and running it. Depending on how you're running your bot, it's possible you're not using the interpreter/virtualenv you think you are.

Comment: 0.16.12 - you were right. I am using visual studio.

Comment: okay so I changed the version but still get this : "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'imgs/image0.png'"

Comment: You probably need to create an `imgs` directory in your project, or change that path to wherever you want the images to go.