# Locally saving an image received on Discord using discord py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've been working on a Discord bot, primarily using Python. The feature I'm currently stuck on, is sending an image to the bot. Once the image, prefix and command are received, I want it to save the image locally so it can be edited. After the edit has been completed, the image has to be sent to sent to the channel, so that the local files can be deleted.

The step I've taken before this is making a website in PHP and sending the image to a MySQL database, as I assumed I'd easily be able to pull the images from it. I was wrong on that end, so I'm starting from scratch.

I'm aware of the image manipulation possibilities with the Pillow library and JavaScript. How can I let the Python bot save the posted image locally?

Comment: [This is probably a good place to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805414/find-the-function-that-save-an-image-when-react-to-on-discord).  Have you written any code yet?

Comment: Only to actually post the image, which is 

`async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('gib img'):
        imgList = os.listdir('../imagesdb')    # Creates a list of filenames from your folder
        imgString = random.choice(imgList)
        path = "../imagesdb/" + imgString      # Creates a string for the path to the file
        await client.send_file(message.channel, path)`

Comment: I wouldn't save locally any image random users may send. And you don't need to actually save the file in order to use it. Instead of saving attachment to disk, why not use a temporary [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) buffer? I personnally do this in order to read text files from users.