# Discord.py Bot cannot work with old messages

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to get reactions from Messages. It Works perfectly fine for messages, that are newer than the Bot, but if I restart the bot, the bot isn't anymore able to work with the reaction My Code looks like this:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
    if user.bot == False:
        print("Got Reaction")
```

But as I just said, I only get the Line 'Got Reaction' If the Message was sent after the last restart from the Bot.
My question is how can I bypass this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [on\_reaction\_add not being run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785641/on-reaction-add-not-being-run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `on_raw_reaction_add`

maybe reading this document [on_raw_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=raw%20reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_add)