# Fetching embed title from on_reaction_add

Tags: python, discord.py

As of right now, I am making a bot that extracts the information from an embed they reacted  to. But when I try to, it doesn't send the content of the embed title I got from `reaction.message.embeds[0].title`.

They way I am getting the reactions data is from a simple `on_reaction_add` event that can be declared after an reacted was added or reacted to (I think).

**How** can I do it?

Comment: I guess, you want to use 'on_raw_reaction_add()' then you will get the reaction events for all (cached/non-cached) messages.

Comment: Try checking this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785641/on-reaction-add-not-being-run

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.