# discord.py on_reaction event not detecting messages after the bot is run

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Whenever we add a reaction to a message that was sent before the bot has started, it goes undetected. Any fixes?

Code: (doesn't really matter to the question)

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  if not user.bot:
    if reaction.message.author.id == bot_id:
      global reactions
      if f'{reaction}' in reactions:
        await VoteAdded(reaction, user)
        await reaction.message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
      else:
        await reaction.message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
```

Comment: From the docs: *”[…] if the message is not found in the internal message cache, then this event will not be called. Consider using `on_raw_reaction_add()` instead.“*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [on\_reaction\_add not being run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785641/on-reaction-add-not-being-run)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `on_reaction_add` function only checks the messages that are in the bot's cache.

To fix this, change the `on_reaction_add` to `on_raw_reaction_add`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add
```

About the `reaction_add` event the [`discord.py documentation`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) says:

> *[...] if the message is not found in the internal message cache, then this event will not be called. Consider using `on_raw_reaction_add()` instead.*

Doing it would probably solve your problem.