# Discord.py Bot does not recognize reactions on message

Tags: python, discord.py

Bot does not recognize reactions on a message that was sent before the bot went online. Do anyone know how I can fix this?

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction: discord.Reaction, user: discord.Member):
  livechannel: discord.TextChannel = bot.get_channel(1015516535223242762)
  if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
    await livechannel.send(user.mention + " *is cool!*")
```

Also the code says that when the user reacts on a specific message the bot will send a message about that in another text channel. But how can I make it so the bot only send one message on the first time when the user reacts so that the user dont spam reacts and unreacts and the bot sends message everytime user reacts.

> This is how I try to use the code as payload:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  livechannel: discord.utils.get(payload.guild.channel, name="live-reactions")
  if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
    await message.livechannel.send(user.mention + " **REACTED WITH ✅! **")
```

> But when I use that code I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'reaction' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to use the [on_raw_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) event instead.
`on_reaction_add` is not able to detect reactions on a message that was sent before the bot went online because the target message is not stored in the cache.

Comment: @Paul I have tried using on_raw_reaction_add but when I use that I get this error: TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Comment: @Jellie raw events dispatch with only one parameter typically called `payload`,  which is a [RawReactionActionEvent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) object in this case.

Comment: @3nws Ok, I have upated the post with the new updated code but I get a error as you can see in the post. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [on\_reaction\_add not being run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785641/on-reaction-add-not-being-run)